# SSH into host on the same network behind a firewall that blocks SSH

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, firewall, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to SSH into my Raspberry Pi, which is on the same wireless network as my SSH client.

My firewall blocks SSH connections.

I changed the `sshd` listening port in my Raspberry Pi to 80 like this: `nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config` > `Port 80` and tried `ssh pi@172.19.4.47 -p 80`. I got this:

```
ssh: connect to host 172.19.4.47 port 80: No route to host
```

Answer (score 0):

If your SSH client machine and your Raspberry Pi device are on the same WLAN, it doesn't matter if the firewall at the edge of that LAN blocks SSH. The firewall blocks SSH clients on the WAN from connecting to SSH servers on LAN/WLAN. It's not going to block SSH connections within the LAN/WLAN.

That `No route to host` error message usually indicates that your client machine can't figure out how to get IP packets to the destination address. Check that both your client machine and your Raspberry Pi are configured to use the same IP subnet. That is, check that they have the same subnet mask, and that the "network" bits of the address are the same on both. For example, if both use a /24 subnet mask (255.255.255.0), make sure both have addresses that start with 172.19.4.x.

Comment: my ip address given is 172.19.7.110 netmask 255.255.240.0
my rapspberry IP is 172.19.4.47 netmask 255.255.240.0. is it normal??? is it means that we're not in the same network??

Comment: @MakhloufGharbi With that netmask, everything from 172.19.0.0 to 172.19.15.255 is on the same subnet.